# Sorting csv file by date and rewriting them on the same file

Tags: python, csv, sorting

I want to sort the csv file by date but there's this error

```
ValueError: time data '.' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'
```

I'm not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

csv file:

```
T.No,Date,Task,Project,Context,Message,Status
1,12/07/2019,meet @sam and @jack,python,@sam,hello,Incomplete
1,11/07/2019,meet @sam and @jack,python,@jack,hello,Incomplete
3,15/07/2019,meet @sam and @ jack,python,@sam & @,at room 12,Incomplete
4,13/07/2019,meet @sam and @jack,python,@sam & @jack,at room 12,Incomplete
5,15/07/2019,meet sam,python,,at room 12,Incomplete
```

```
    def sort():
        data = open("csv.csv", 'r')
        stdata = sorted(data, key=lambda row: datetime.strptime(row[1], "%d/%m/%Y"))
        with open("csv.csv", 'w') as f1:
            writer = csv.writer(f1)
            for eachline in stdata:
                writer.writerows(eachline)
```

Comment: please add the in post not in google drive

Comment: can you copy-paste some of your data here?

Comment: done i copy-pasted the csv file contents here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier to use [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) for reading CSV and sorting operations:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('csv.csv', index_col=False)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df.sort_values('Date', inplace=True)
df.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
T.No,Date,Task,Project,Context,Message,Status
1,07/11/2019,meet @sam and @jack,python,@jack,hello,Incomplete
1,07/12/2019,meet @sam and @jack,python,@sam,hello,Incomplete
4,13/07/2019,meet @sam and @jack,python,@sam & @jack,at room 12,Incomplete
3,15/07/2019,meet @sam and @ jack,python,@sam & @,at room 12,Incomplete
5,15/07/2019,meet sam,python,,at room 12,Incomplete
```

Comment: also a nice way :)

Comment: This is a great way but I'm preferring to not use pandas

Comment: also if I use this is there a way to get the sorted data in the same format?

Comment: Thanks @Alderven it really helped

Answer (score 2):

You could use `headers = next(reader)` to remove the first row not including a date.

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv

with open('data.csv', newline='') as csv_file:  
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    headers = next(reader) #removing the first row from your reader 

    sorted_reader = sorted(reader, key = lambda row: datetime.strptime(str(row[1]), "%d/%m/%Y"))

    for row in sorted_reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: This works but what if I want to write it to the same csv file or a different one

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
datetime.strptime("2009/10/2", "%Y/%m/%d")
```

Comment: Hey,
I know this works but I'm reading from a csv file so need something more

Comment: print row[1] and tell me about type and value